# How to update a field on child record if a parent record gets deleted

Tags: salesforce1-app, process-builder

I am trying to update a field in my child record automatically when a parent record gets deleted.
I have 2 objects, 1. Team 2. Player. I have lookup relationship between both objects. 
Team is parent object. There is a checkbox field in player object called, is free agent. Each player is related to a team. What i want to do is, I want to check the "**is free agent**" check box once the related team to this player gets deleted.
I am trying to do it using process builder. I cannot use apex triggers. Because I am practicing salesforce built-in UI tools.

here is what i have tried.
Checking criteria if lookup field is empty in player object
[image]

updating is free agent check box
[image: updating is free agent check box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process Builder does not support "on delete" events. You would need a trigger to update such a field. However, if you're just interested in a checkbox that can't be updated, you might use a formula field instead:

```
Is Free Agent (checkbox)

ISBLANK(Team__c)
```

This would be the "non-coding" way of doing this in Salesforce.

Comment: @sfdfox, Thank you. It was a useful information. I did not know that about process builder and ur answer solved my problem.